# jQuery - Combing If/ Else + .Click() and .prop('disabled', true);

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would LOVE some help on this as I've searched on StackOverFlow and found a way to disable the button from clicking IF no info is entered into the form, (using the $.trim(.....) code below! Yay! 
Problem is - once I add that in, the rest of the code in the "else" part doesn't work. Scratching my head as to WHY?!!

If I comment out this section to disable the click then the user can click the button irrespective if any info is entered (but rest of code works fine) -

```
if ($.trim($('.inputs').val()).length == 0){
$('.inputs').prop('disabled', true);
} else { ....... }
```

My HTML -

```
<div class="entry"> 
<h2>Enter the Contest:</h2>
<form>
<p class="inputs"><label>Name : </label><input type="text"   placeholder=" required" id="name-input" required></p>
<p class="inputs"><label>Hole #: </label><input type="number" placeholder=" required" id="hole-input" required></p> 
<p class="inputs"><label>Par #: </label><input type="number" placeholder=" required" id="par-input" required></p>
<p class="inputs"><label>Strokes #: </label><input type="number" placeholder=" required" id="strokes-input" required></p>   
<button id="submit" class="btn1">Submit</button>    
</form>
</div>
```

My jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn1").click(function(){

if ($.trim($('.inputs').val()).length == 0){
$('.inputs').prop('disabled', true); 
} else { 
$(".entry h2").replaceWith("<h2>Submitted!</h2>");
$("form").hide().replaceWith("<p>" + golfScore() + "! <br>Thank you for entering the contest and good luck!</p>");
$(".entry p").addClass("inputs message");
$(".entry").append("<button>Replay?</button>");
$(".entry button").addClass("btn2");
$(".btn2").on('click', refreshPage); 
} // closes else
});     
}); // closes Doc Ready
```

Comment: Your elements with the `inputs` class are paragraphs, and paragraphs don't have a value. And neither can they be disabled. So start by selecting the right elements.

Comment: And when a selector matches multiple elements, `$(selector).val()` returns the value of the first matching element, not all of them.

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve this! Wouldn't this apply to the info added into the form - which would be a value? In my case I have one input with TEXT and three with NUMBER. When I use the if ($.trim.... etc) snippet of code I do like how I get a pop up alert that reminds the user to enter in some info in order to submit.

Comment: _"Wouldn't this apply to the info added into the form - which would be a value?"_ - not, it would not. That is added into the input fields - _those_ have a value that you can query by using `.val()`, not the paragraph elements, that just happen to contain the inputs (which doesn't make them form elements.) _"When I use the if ($.trim.... etc) "_ ... then you are trimming _nothing_, an empty string, because that's what .val returns for paragraphs. _"the rest of the code in the "else" part doesn't work"_ - no, it does never even come to execution, because your faulty if condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

try this -- 
example :

```
 $("input").on("change keyup",function(){
 //remove the disabled then do the rest -- 

    $('.btn1').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    // start checking if the input boxes have values

     if ($.trim($('#name-input').val()).length == 0){
     // you can also set focus to the field that is empty
            $('.btn1').prop('disabled', true); 
            return false;

     }if ($.trim($('#hole-input').val()).length == 0){

            $('.btn1').prop('disabled', true); 
            return false;

     }if ($.trim($('#par-input').val()).length == 0){

            $('.btn1').prop('disabled', true); 
            return false;

     }if ($.trim($('#strokes-input').val()).length == 0){

            $('.btn1').prop('disabled', true); 
            return false;

     } else { 
     // if all has been passed should execute code
        $(".entry h2").replaceWith("<h2>Submitted!</h2>");

        $("form").hide().replaceWith("<p>" + golfScore() + "! <br>Thank you for entering the contest and good luck!</p>");

        $(".entry p").addClass("inputs message");

        $(".entry").append("<button>Replay?</button>");

        $(".entry button").addClass("btn2");

        $(".btn2").on('click', refreshPage);

    } // closes else
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Linc. I haven't used change keyup before. This method totally works. It seems to bypass the need to press the SUBMIT button ... I'm assuming because of "keyup". But it does the trick! THANK YOU!!

Comment: awesome glad it helped !